# What does |= do in C?

Tags: c, operator-keyword

I am trying to understand what the C Operator `|=` do:

```
// Initialize the green led
// Enable the clock for PORT D.  See Page 216 of the Datasheet
SIM_SCGC5 |= (1U<<12);

// Enable the mux as GPIO.  See Page 193 of the Datasheet
PORTD_PCR5 = 0x100;
```

I also don't understand what the `0x100` means.

Comment: `a |= b;` is `a = a | b;` like `a += b;` is `a = a + b;` etc.

Comment: 0x100 is the hexadecimal representation for 256;

Comment: Wow, I can't believe no-one's actually asked this question before on SO. I'm basing that on the fact you didn't find it when you searched. You *did* search, didn't you? :-)

Comment: I did @paxdiablo. I guess Google aint that good with searching Operators. Thanks anyway ;-)

Comment: "c operators" would have given you zillion hits.

Comment: Bracketz, a search of "C operator" (using SO rather than Google) turned up an earlier question. Hopefully the answers there will assist.

Comment: They did @paxdiablo. Thanks man!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [bitwise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) OR compound assignment, it is the same as  :

```
SIM_SCGC5 = SIM_SCGC5 | (1U<<12);
```

The `0x100` it is the value 100 in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), the 0x prefix means hexadecimal value.